# OpenFB : Invalid Scope: function

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework

I'm using OpenFB (https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB) with ionicframework.

When I try to login From localhost It works very fine. When I uploaded my files to another server and I specify the right URL in facebook app, I'm getting this error : Invalid Scope: function

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's telling you the error which no one here will be able to see without the full URL and/or code snippet.

You are supplying a scope labelled `function` which is not a specified scope in the API.